# Can i remove markers and labels on google static map in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Anyone know if can I remove default markers and labels in google static map in my Laravel project ? Its should show only street names [image: google-map-issue]

i was tried to find parameter that can help me but it useless

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find more info about the params here: [static maps api styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/styling?hl=en)

I think that you need to hide poi (points of interest) and transit adding this manually to the final url:

```
&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:transit|element:labels|visibility:off
```

Analyzing your code i think that you are using [laravel-google-static-map](https://github.com/mastani/laravel-google-static-map) and this library does not have a method to generate this part